# Android Eclipse In Ubuntu

Tags: android, development

I am having  an Error When Launching Eclipse For Android Developmet.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Pleae Help me to Solve this Error.

Answer (score 0):

Installing or reinstalling the `zlib1g` package will solves `libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` error.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall zlib1g
```

Comment: E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
naeem@naeem-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g
[sudo] password for naeem: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: reinstall the same package.

Comment: How ?to Reinsatll the Package

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: `sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8`

Comment: Avinash   I am not Getting It.

Comment: Post the output of locate libz.so.1

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/home/naeem/workspace/appcompat_v7/bin/appcompat_v7.jar' vis  Build path Build Path Problem

Comment: Getting This Error Also

Comment: Then the first error asked in the question is solved?

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing Library.My first Error